Linux Mint 22 не видит Wi-Fi
В линуксе я новичок, поэтому скачал самый простой, как говорят на форумах, дистрибутив Mint, т.к там меньше настроек и проще установка. Установил, но вот сети вай-фай он не видит. Как выяснилось драйвера нет. Скачал драйвер от Mediatek MT7630E. И выполнил следующие команды по инструкции из папки с драйвером:
chmod +x install test uninstall bpatch

sudo ./install

На что получил ошибку:
Нет правила для сборки цели "стол/MT7630E-master/rtx00"
Загуглил, пишут типо ошибка в Makefile, а что с этим делать - без понятия
Ещё, если это как-то поможет, был Ubuntu 22.04, там тоже аналогичная проблема была,я его снёс и сейчас  Mint установил. В общем 2 дня сижу, разные форумы перелопатил, не хочет ставиться этот драйвер и всё, хелп...

Перенеси папку с рабочего стола в домашнюю папкуч и выполни оттуда. И ещё, откуда вы качали драйвер?
